# can't open simple pdf created with latex with gscan2pdf

Tags: pdf, latex

So, I want to make one pdf from multiple. For this, I decided to use gscan2pdf. I have a bunch of "image-pdfs" that open just fine.

I have to insert a page with just a few lines of text on it. I created a simple pdf in latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Titel}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
test
\end{document}
```

That's it. It compiles perfectly fine. I can open it with my normal pdf reader. But, when I try to open it with gscan2pdf I get the following error every time:

Warning: gscan2pdf expects one image per page, but this was not satisfied. It is probable that the PDF has not been correcly imported.

If you wish to add scans to an existing PDF, use the prepend/append to PDF options in the Save dialogue.

---

What happens and how do I open the pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gscan2pdf creates PDF files that contain bitmap graphics. With latex, however, you created a PDF file containing text, i.e., containing information about the characters and their position, the font of the characters etc. gscan2pdf produces and reads PDF's with graphics, and appears to choke if you feed it a PDF not containing any bitmap graphics.

In the end, your decision to use gscan2pdf to create one pdf from multiple may have been the wrong decision. A tool like PDF Arranger or similar may fit your purpose better.